# Listening to clicks on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been struggling to implement a click listener on a RecyclerView.  I have seen a couple of approaches and would prefer to handle ImageView clicks from the Activity as I need to do pass an Intent to another Activity and do some work off the main thread.  Here is what I have implemented so far:

Register the click in a Custom RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class BasemapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BasemapViewHolder> {

// Context to construct view
private Context mContext;
// Copy of all BasemapItems
private ArrayList<BasemapItem> items;

private int rowLayout;

public BasemapAdapter(ArrayList<BasemapItem> portalItems, int rowLayout, Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.items = portalItems;
    this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
}

@Override
public BasemapViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);

    return new BasemapViewHolder(view);

}

/**
 * Fill the view with data from our adapter
 *
 * @param viewHolder
 * @param position
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BasemapViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){
    // get the element from your dataset at this position
    // replace the contents of the view with the element
    viewHolder.basemapImage.setImageBitmap(items.get((position)).basemapImage);
    viewHolder.basemapName.setText(items.get((position)).item.getTitle());

    viewHolder.setBasemapClickListener(new BasemapViewHolder.BasemapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBasemapItemClicked(View view, int position) {
            Log.d("TAG", "clicked at " + position);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return items == null ? 0 : items.size();
}
}
```

Custom ViewHolder

```
public class BasemapViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

@InjectView(R.id.basemapName) TextView basemapName;
@InjectView(R.id.basemapImage) ImageView basemapImage;

private BasemapClickListener clickListener;

public BasemapViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);

    // set listener to whole item view
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    clickListener.onBasemapItemClicked(v, getPosition());
}

/* setter for the listener */
public void setBasemapClickListener(BasemapClickListener clickListener){
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

/**
 * A callback interface that indicates when a basemap has been clicked
 */
public interface BasemapClickListener{
    /**
     * Callback when the view is clicked
     *
     * @param view view that is clicked
     * @param position position of the clicked basemap
     */
    public void onBasemapItemClicked(View view, int position);


}

}
```

Create an instance of the adapter in Activity

```
mBasemapAdapter = new BasemapAdapter( mBasemapList , R.layout.row_basemap, this);

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mBasemapAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by setting the onClickListener on the TextView as it was overlaying the ImageView:

BasemapAdapter

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BasemapViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){
    final BasemapItem item = items.get(position);
    // get the element from your dataset at this position
    // replace the contents of the view with the element
    viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(items.get(position).getImage());
    viewHolder.title.setText(items.get(position).getItem().getTitle());

    viewHolder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(item != null){
                clickListener.onImageClick(items.indexOf(item));
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.itemView.setTag(item);
}
```

Then I can call the onBaseMapClickListener from inside the Activity

```
        mBasemapAdapter.setOnBaseMapClickListener(new BasemapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageClick(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tapped" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the ImageView clicks only your should do it as follows:

```
@InjectView(R.id.basemapName) TextView basemapName;
@InjectView(R.id.basemapImage) ImageView basemapImage;

private BasemapClickListener clickListener;

public BasemapViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);

    // set listener to whole item view
    //itemView.setOnClickListener(this); // comment out this line
    basemapImage.setOnClickListener(this); // <---- add this line
}
```

and you should move setBasemapClickListener from onBindViewHolder() to onCreateViewHolder().

```
@Override
public BasemapViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
view.setBasemapClickListener(new BasemapViewHolder.BasemapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBasemapItemClicked(View view, int position) {
            Log.d("TAG", "clicked at " + position);
        }
    });
    return new BasemapViewHolder(view);

}
```

Comment: I have been going back and forth between the setting the listener on the whole item view or the ImageView.  Neither has worked for me.

Comment: @jdONeill check my edit and see. If it doesnt work tell me if void onClick(View v) is called or not.

Comment: Currently setOnBasemapClickListener() is on BasemapViewHolder which is a parameter in onBindViewHolder() so cannot make that change.  I had previously set it as an inner class on BasemapAdapter and tried in the onBindViewHolder() off of the view but code never reached onClick()

Comment: @jdONeill It is odd. Try using findviewbyid instead of Injection for imageview to see if it works.

Comment: Yep, tried that right before posing question, no luck. I have a simple app working so really baffled now.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with my layout being a android.support.v7.widget.CardView?  I have a simple working prototype that works and this is the only difference.